# Gradle Connection Reset

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

So I wanted to make an app but gradle start making me a hard time.

When I first start a new project I get this error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Unable to determine version for JDK located at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk. Reason: Command returned unexpected result code: 1
```

When I am changing the gradle JDK version to 16 I get this error:

```
Gradle sync failed: Connection reset
```

These are the errors:
https://ibb.co/k4MLsWC

These are the settings:
https://ibb.co/cg9sbXP

Android Gradle Plugin Version: **7.0.4**
Gradle Version: **7.0.2**

I am trying to make this work for almost 4 hours........

Any help is welcome,Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after a loooonggg time the solusion is to delete .gradle folder in:

```
C:\Users\<Your User Name>
```

After that, start android studio and it will create all the needed files.